# symfony 2 - Language version - No route found for “GET /”

Tags: php, symfony, routes, multilingual, symfony-routing

Symfony2 returns No route found for "GET /nl" when I try to run http://localhost/nl

**app/config/routing.yml**

```
    #hwi_oauth_redirect:
    #    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/redirect.xml"
    #    prefix:   /connect
    # 
    #hwi_oauth_login:
    #    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/login.xml"
    #    prefix:   /login

    softlogo_works:
        resource: "@SoftlogoWorksBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
        prefix:   /{_locale}/
        requirements:
            _locale: en|pl|ru|fr|nl


    #softlogo_news:
        #resource: "@SoftlogoNewsBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
        #prefix:   /

    sonata:
        resource: "@SoftlogoCMSBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata.yml"
        prefix:   /

        #host:     "{host}"
        #requirements:
            #host: "[a-zA-Z1-9\.\-]+"
        #defaults: {host: "ngmina.localhost"}


    gallery:
        resource: '@SonataMediaBundle/Resources/config/routing/gallery.xml'
        prefix: /media/gallery
    media:
        resource: '@SonataMediaBundle/Resources/config/routing/media.xml'
        prefix: /media

    news:
        resource: '@SonataNewsBundle/Resources/config/routing/news.xml'
        prefix: /{_locale}/news
        requirements:
            _locale: en|pl|ru|fr|nl

    softlogo_portfolio:
        resource: "@SoftlogoPortfolioBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
        prefix:   /{_locale}/projekty
        requirements:
            _locale: en|pl|ru|fr|nl

    softlogo_product:
        resource: "@SoftlogoProductBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
        prefix:   /product
        requirements:
            _locale: en|pl|ru|fr|nl
    softlogo_shop:
        resource: "@SoftlogoShopBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
        prefix:   /shop
        requirements:
            _locale: en|pl|ru|fr|nl
    #softlogo_portfolio:
    #softlogo_portfolio:
    #    resource: "@SoftlogoPortfolioBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    #    prefix:   /portfolio
    #
    softlogo_cms:
        resource: "@SoftlogoCMSBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
        prefix:   /
    simple_things_entity_audit:
        resource: "@SimpleThingsEntityAuditBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
        prefix: /audit
```

**app/config/routing_dev.yml:**

```
_wdt:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/wdt.xml"
    prefix:   /_wdt

_profiler:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/profiler.xml"
    prefix:   /_profiler

_configurator:
    resource: "@SensioDistributionBundle/Resources/config/routing/webconfigurator.xml"
    prefix:   /_configurator

_errors:
    resource: "@TwigBundle/Resources/config/routing/errors.xml"
    prefix:   /_error

_main:
    resource: routing.yml
```

**Error Page:**

[image: Error Page]

The site contains 5 language versions but the problem only occurs in the nl version, all others work properly. 
I have already cleaned the cache folder, but no effects.

What can be the problem?

Comment: What happens if you use a trailing slash?

Comment: What route do you expect to be run?  What is output from `bin/console debug:router` or is displayed for `bin/console router:match /nl`

Comment: When I use a trailing slash - nothing changes. Same problem

Comment: what is your symfony version?

Comment: My version is 2.7.15

Comment: can you show all routes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your added an extra '/' at the end of prefix

```
softlogo_works:
    resource: "@SoftlogoWorksBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /{_locale}
    requirements:
        _locale: en|pl|ru|fr|nl
```

Answer (score 0):

You should enable locale in `app/config/config.yml`

```
parameters:
    locale: en

framework:
    #esi: ~
    translator: { fallbacks: ['%locale%'] }
```